# CDATA in partial response closes after start of encoding of custom component

Tags: jsf-2, custom-component

I have a custom component:

```
<g:get name="conf_temporadas" anchorid="nombre" defaulttext="nombre" customer="9999" nohtml="true" />
```

which just gets a simple text from a database based on the attributes and prints.

When I update an element that contains this component, the XML is not correct because the XML CDATA close after the `<g:get>` is printed.

```
<p:outputPanel id="noticePanel">
  <div class="wrapbox notice"> 
    <a href="#Cerrar" title="Cerrar" class="close">    
      <g:get name="form_common" anchorid="cerrar" defaulttext="Cerrar" customer="9999" nohtml="true"/>
    </a>
    <p><h:outputText  value="#{Notice.noticeMessage}" id="notice" escape="false"></h:outputText></p>
    #{Notice.clearNotice}
  </div>
</p:outputPanel>
```

When I update the `<p:outputPanel>`, the error is:

> Error de lectura XML: etiqueta sin pareja. Se esperaba: `</update>`. Ubicación: moz-nullprincipal:{8fefe5c1-e8c7-4342-837a-3b4bae9dfc19} Número de línea 2, columna 116: `<span id="i_notice:j_id_b">Cerrar]]> </span></a>`

As you can see, after "Cerrar" the CDATA is closed. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is this `<g:get>` component?  What is the `g` namespace supposed to be?  I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @maple: I cite from the 1st paragraph: *"custom component"*. So, it's a custom component :) @TinGinard: it would be helpful if you show the necessary `encode` methods. Perpahs you closed the tag or attribute the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is at the custom component ResponseWriter of the encode Method, I call `ResponseWriter#close` and in that moment, the CDATA gets CLOSE ]].

I just remove the `ResponseWriter#close`, and everything works as a charm

Thanks you all, for your answers, BalusC, you show me the way.